# What is the maximum number of y-axis that you can add to a highcharts chart?

Tags: highcharts, yaxis

So, I have an existing project that uses "highcharts" library and as a requirement we need to add support for multiple y-axis.
I want to know what is the maximum number of axes allowed, there is a limit?
I have done some searching but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation for axes. Below you can find an example with 100 `yAxis`:

```
yAxis: (function() {
    var axes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        axes.push({
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'axis ' + i
            }
        });

    }
    return axes;
})()
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/syg7atzw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limitation of Axis in Hightchart.

You can see examples here : [Examples Multiple y-Axis](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)